# GCP BigQuery and MongoDB APIs

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to get an idea of the difficulty of migrating from BigQuery to MongoDB. In regards to the APIs, how different are they and how big of a code change could it require for even the most simple tasks. Does anyone know if there are any wrappers out there that could help so moving from BigQuery to MongoDB isn't as painful.

Comment: Why are you doing that? What are you looking for?

Comment: MongoDB isnt available for what I want at the moment so going to try out BigQuery or BigTable. Or looking for other suggestions to make that transition smoother

Comment: It's totally different and the usage specific to your use case. Don't expect low latency with BigQuery, don't expect aggregation with BigTable. If different tools exist, it's for different reasons!